Questions about install Ubuntu 22.04 lts in dual boot with windows 11 on dell precision 3571
everything good?
I want to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in dual boot on a Dell Precision 3571 notebook with Windows 11 Pro.
The notebook already has an SSD of almost 1TB and another just for data, the intention is to leave 200GB for Windows and the rest for Ubuntu, which is what I will use most frequently. It also has a good amount of memory: 64GB RAM.
So, I have some doubts.
1 - As the bios has a uefi unit, and I want to use the bios system itself to manage boots, not needing grub. I want to know about creating the boot partition for UEFI, in this case how much space do you need for this partition? What is the type of this partition, in this case it is a reserved bios boot area or an efi system partition? Because I've seen tutorials using both a reserved area and an EFI system partition, so I don't know what's right for this installation. And lastly, the device on which to install the bootloader, in which case where or where should I install this bootloader? Because I've seen tutorials telling you to install it on the same drive where Ubuntu is being installed, and others telling you to install it on the same drive as Windows, and others installing it in a standard way, leaving already selected what the installation system already has marked and following the installation.
2 - About whether or not to create a swap partition. Knowing that the notebook already has a good amount of memory, 64GB, is it necessary to create a swap partition? If so, how much space would be needed for this partition? I have already obtained information that for newer versions of Ubuntu a swap partition is not necessary, but I am unsure.
3 - About the need to create the /home partition. I don't know if I don't create one, if the system itself is already responsible for creating one or does it necessarily need to be created? If you need to create, in my case, I will already have a separate space for data, such as image files, videos, sounds, etc. How much space would you need for the home? I intend to use some virtual machines, but I can't predict how much space it will take up.
Thank you in advance for the information.

If UEFI system, you want UEFI not the old BIOS from before 2012. My newer Dell with 11th Gen Intel chip says BIOS, but once in "BIOS" it says UEFI only. Your specs show 12th Gen Intel, so may be UEFI only? If drive is larger, ESP should be 400 to 600MB, but Windows often had 100MB and you could easily dual boot as grub does not take much space. Extra space for future use as resizing first partition can be difficult. Swap partiton should be 4.1GB, but default is now swap file, often smaller. A /home partition optional, but if very large / over 100GB better to separate /home.


In order to boot from UEFI you need a ESP partition (a special FAT filesystem, the partition needs to have a GPT partition guid of C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B ) of recommended size 100MB (you can have it smaller or larger, both windows and Linux default install is ~100MB).  You can have multiple UEFI partitions on the same disk, and use your system boot process to select what partition is used to boot.  Each ESP partition can have a boot loader installed on it.

Alternatively you can have a boot partition on each of your drives.  As long as the partition is ESP.
***Note:  It is not best practice to have more than one UEFI boot partition on a single drive, but it will work.

I would personally use rEFInd it is easy to setup, and a heap of options and is easily configured.


You do not need to have a swap partition, if you do have a swap I would have at least half of your memory, up to the same amount of your memory.

Rather then creating a partition for swap, you can use a image on the drive as swap memory eg:
      dd if=/dev/zero of=swap.img bs=512K count=4000
      chmod 0600 swap.img
      swapon swap.img




As for the creation of the Home partition, this is more a personal preference and/or based on the system and what the system will be used for.  If there is going to be a lot of files stored in home directories, then I would recommend having home on a separate partition to ensure your root partition always has space available for key system files.



Thanks for the answers, I was even confusing UEFi with Bios, I thought it was an evolved Bios.

In this case, I will create a 200mb ESP type partition on the Linux drive just in case.
One more question, if I'm going to use this program, rEFInd, do I still need to have installed, during the Linux installation, the boot system on the ESP partition of the Linux drive? Or does this program already replace the boot system and I don't need to install it?



I think I'll go this way and create an image as memory instead of a partition.
I don't think I'm going to create a specific partition for /home, because in this case, there will be almost 800GB for Linux and I will already have a specific SSD just for data.


No you do not need linux to install the boot system, refind will find the linux iunstallation and add it to the boot menu.  Using refind makes it easier to have all the efi binaries in the same location, and control the config files.
